# SAS - get maximum of a variable and store as a column in the dataset

Tags: sas

Say, for example, I have the following data

```
Dataset name: TheTable
Name      Age      Height
Peter     21        1.6
Alexa     19        1.8
Rob       23        1.3
```

I want to get the largest age and height, and store them in the table as follows

```
Dataset name: TheTableWithMax
Name      Age      Height     MaxAge     maxHeight
Peter     21        1.6       23         1.8
Alexa     19        1.8       23         1.8      
Rob       23        1.3       23         1.8
```

The reason for this is that I have to draw a comparison between each variable and the maximum of that variable. How can I go about doing that in SAS?

I have thought of doing the following in order to obtain the max of, say, the Age column (the same process will be done for the Height column)

```
proc sort data = TheTable (obs=1) out=MaxAge (keep = Age);
  by descending Age;
run;
```

However, I am not sure how I will be able to merge that back with the original TheTable to get TheTablewithMax.

Any assistance will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easily done with `proc sql` and summary functions, in your case `max()`:

```
proc sql;
create table TheTableWithMax as
select *
      ,max(age) as MaxAge
      ,max(height) as MaxHeight
from TheTable
;
quit;
```